# How to Push Content Block Down 2-Pixels

Tags: css, html-lists

I have a `<ul>` block with `<li>` lists that form a sub menu. When you hover over the main menu bar (page link below), the green border-top bar is 2 pixels too high and I cannot figure out how to move it down to exactly overlay the blue bar a top of the page body section.

http://bit.ly/1IgmNKT

Anyway suggestions are greatly appreciated. Thanks.

**Appended Note for Caution:**
I have tried many styles to push the block down 2 pixels but the ones I have tried end up breaking the flow of the sub-menu hover navigation which results in the sub-menu disappearing on hover.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Add clearfix to you main menu div 
  `#menu-main-menu:after {
  content: '';
  clear: both;
  display: table;
  }`
- Push menu items 2px from top: 
  `#menu-main-menu > .menu-item { margin-top: 2px;}`
- Go drink beer

Comment: ha ha...I think "Go Drink Beer" comes first :)

Comment: Excellent @BogdanKuštan -- this solved it. So greatly appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly then you are talking about to shift submenu down by 2px. if so then try following css code

**CSS**

```
.nav-menu {
    float:left;
    height:60px;
}
```

Comment: However you need to add more padding at the bottom, because Your submenu is lower than parent item. Su Hovering is not working :)

Comment: I have tried that style before @NileshMahajan and while it pushes the block down 2 pixels the problem is that once you mouse down to hover over the sub menus, they disappear (at least they do in Chrome).

Comment: @H.Ferrence: if my answer is useful to you you can mark it correct :)

Comment: It's close @NileshMahajan but it is ultimately not the answer as it breaks the hover navigation. Sorry.

Comment: @H.Ferrence: check my updated code. it will work for you now.

Comment: agree totally @NileshMahajan -- arrogant down voters are so nonconstructive without an explanation as to why. Down Voting is one of the worst features here at SO -- at least to those of us who come here to learn.

Comment: I upvoted you @NileshMahajan for your help and assistance. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
nav#site-navigation ul.sub-menu {
  margin-top: 2px;
  border-top: 10px solid #a4c74c;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

Comment: Your answer achieves the 2-pixel push but breaks the hover navigation @AakashAggarwal

Comment: How does it break the navigation? Can you be more specific?

Comment: Try it...hover over the sub menu to see the effect

Answer (score 0):

First and last dropdown have

```
nav#site-navigation ul.sub-menu{z-index: 1;}
```

and middle one:

```
 ul#menu-main-menu li.menu-item-has-children.pulldown-button ul.sub-menu{z-index:3;}
```

That is why your menu is "disappearing".